# What's the point of the Day of Judgement?

Tags: catholicism

What's the point of the Day of Judgement if when you die you already get decided if you're going to heaven or hell? What's the point of judgement day if you're already judged?

Comment: A formal judgement is for public benefit, not your own. If you are guilty, a public listing of that guilt removes public doubt.

Comment: Actually, "[From a Catholic viewpoint, why will there be a particular judgement and a general judgment?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/48353/1787)" seems more related to this questions.